# Filling a Triangle in Python

Tags: python, function, math, fill

I have a python program where the object is to have the user enter the length of the sides of a triangle, if they would like to fill it, and what color. I keep getting an attribute error pertaining to GeometricObject and fill.

After a few fixes I am stuck in the same area again (fill), this is the error I keep getting:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Desktop/one.py", line 81,
> in <module>
>     main()   File "Desktop/one.py", line 78, in main
>     "Is filled? :  ", triangle.ColorFill())   File "Desktop/one.py", line 21, in ColorFill
>     return self.__filled AttributeError: 'Triangle' object has no attribute '_GeometricObject__filled'
```

I am not sure where to untangle this, any help would be welcomed. Below is my code:

## 12.1 The Triangle class

```
import math

#class for the GeometricObject, must be defined before Trianble. includes fill
class GeometricObject:
    #if true the color will be green
    def __init__(self, color =" ", filled = True):
        self.__color = color
        self__filled = filled
    #getting the fill color and setting it to green fill
    def getColor(self):
        return self.__color
    def setColor(self, color):
        self.__color = color
    def ColorFill(self):
        return self.__filled
    def setColorFill(self, filled):
        self__filled = filled
    #string that tells you if it is filled or not
    def __st__(self):
        return "Color is: " + (self.__color) \
               + "Fill: " + str(self.__filled)
    
#setting class for triangle and calling on geometric objects
class Triangle(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, side1 = 1.0, side2 = 1.0, side3 = 1.0):
        self.__side1 = side1
        self.__side2 = side2
        self.__side3 = side3
        #calling GeometricObject, this is what triangle is bound to
        GeometricObject.__init__(self)
     #getting length of sides       
    def getLengthA(self):
        return side1
    def getLengthB(self):
        return side2
    def getLengthC(self):
        return side3
    #setting and getting perimeter
    def setPerimeter(self):
        self.perimeter = perimeter
    def getPerimeter(self):
        perimeter = self.__side1 + self.__side2 + self.__side3
        return perimeter
    #setting and getting area
    def setArea(self):
        self.area = area
    def getArea(self):
        s = (self.__side1 + self.__side2 + self.__side3) / 2
        area = math.sqrt(s * ((s - self.__side1) * (s - self.__side2) * (s - self.__side3)))
        return area
    #printing string, sides
    def toString(self):
        return "Triangle: Side 1: " + (self.__side1)\
               + "Side 2: " + (self.__side2)\
               + "Side 3: " + (self.__side3)
    
def main():
    #user enters sides of a triangle
    side1, side2, side3 = eval(input("Enter the length of the Tiangle's sides (A, B, C):  "))
    triangle = Triangle(side1, side2, side3)
    #user enters color
    color = input("Enter a color: ")
    triangle.setColor(color)
    #user enter if filled
    filled = eval(input("Enter 1 to fill with color \n Enter 0 for no fill: "))
    ColorFill = (filled == 1)
    triangle.setColorFill(ColorFill)

    print("The area of the triangle is: " ,  triangle.getArea(), \
          "The perimeter is: " , triangle.getPerimeter(), \
          "The color is: ", triangle.getColor(), \
          "Is filled? :  ", triangle.ColorFill())


main()
```

Comment: Change `self__filled` to `self.__filled` in `GeometricObject`'s constructor. Edit: And everywhere else.

Comment: There appear to be two methods (__init__ and setColorFill) where you've got "self__something" instead of "self.__something". If you correct those typos, you may find things work better.

Comment: Thank you! it's always the small stuff isn't it?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Could you turn your comment into an answer so the OP can accept it?

Comment: @NiayeshIsky I don't think that's necessary... it's just a typo and should be closed as such.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Fair enough. I was reading [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/7315159) earlier and overthought this :)